# Limit of $\frac{\sin(xy^2)}{x^2+y^2}$ as $x\to0$ and $y\to0$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Does anybody have an idea, how to solve this limit, I cant figure it out. I wanted to try some algebraic magic to get something with $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ but without success. Any sugestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\left\lvert\frac{\sin(xy^{2})}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\right\rvert\le\left\lvert\frac{xy^{2}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\right\rvert=\left\lvert\frac{y^{2}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\right\rvert\cdot \lvert x\rvert$$

This tends to $0$ since $y^{2}\le x^{2}+y^{2}$.

Answer (score 4):

Try writing it as
$$\frac{\sin(xy^2)}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{\sin(xy^2)}{xy^2}\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^2}$$
Then
$$\frac{\sin(xy^2)}{xy^2} \rightarrow 1$$

So you just have to evaluate the limit of 
$$\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^2}$$ which is zero
since $$\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{x}{(\frac{x}{y})^2 +1} \leq x.$$